# Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel hide non-matched rows

Tags: extjs

I'm using a [Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel) and i want to hide all rows that have no match.

When the search field is empty, I want all elements to be displayed.

I'm using a Ext.data.Store that contains my data.

I tried to find a config for this, but had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle search field and filter store by this value. Something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', {

    ...

    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            var me = this,
                store = me.getStore();

            me.textField.on('change', function(cmp) {
                var searchValue = cmp.getValue();

                store.clearFilter(true);

                if (!searchValue) {
                    return;
                }

                store.filter(function(record) {
                    // you can filter store by some column
                    var companyName = record.get('company'); 

                    if (!me.caseSensitive) {
                        companyName = companyName.toLowerCase();
                        searchValue = searchValue.toLowerCase();
                    }

                    if (me.regExpMode) {
                        var match = companyName.match(searchValue);

                        return match ? this.indexOf(match[0]) : -1;
                    }

                    return companyName.indexOf(searchValue) != -1;
                });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

---

**[Look my fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/f4a)**